# Как убрать фокус пробела на pushButton?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, button

У меня есть `pushbutton(close_button)` при нажатии на которую окно закрывается и `pushbutton(minimize_button)` при нажатии на нее окно сворачивается.

Как мы знаем пробел выполняет повторяет последнее действие, то есть если я один раз сверну окно, то при нажатии на пробел оно свернется еще раз, так же по умолчанию фокус пробела стоит на кнопке закрывающей окно.

Возможно ли убрать в принципе фокус пробела с кнопок?

Так же мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на пробел ничего не происходило так как суть моей программы подсвечивать нажатые кнопку.

Мой код если понадобится:

https://pastebin.com/NZSV2bSG - форма
https://pastebin.com/g36sFDkS - основной код

Answer (score 5, accepted):

для кнопочек надо установить фокус полиси:

```
setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus)
```

более детально тут: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop

---

В вашем случае:

```
...
class Example(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        ...
        self.close_button.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)              
        self.minimize_button.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)   
 ...
```